# Traducción del nodo padre usando archivos yml para la traducción i18n

Tags: ruby, i18n

Tengo un menu dinamico el cual debe poder se traducido a varios idiomas para lo que uso i18n.

El menu tiene la siguiente estructura:

- Padre1

  - hijo1
  - hijo 2
- Padre2

  - hijo1

Para lo que me gustaria poder crear un archivo de traducción de tipo **en.yml**

```
en: 
  padre1: "father1"
  padre1: 
    hijo1: "son1"
    hijo2: "son2"
  padre2: "father2"
    hijo1: "son1"
```

Pero la vista me imprime en Padre1 :

```
{:"HIJO1"=>"SON1", "HIJO2"=> "SON2"}
```

**¿ Cual tendría que ser la estructura para poder traducir un menu anidado sin perder la jerarquía ?**

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estás asignando dos valores a padre1, primero

```
  padre1: "father1"
```

y luego

```
  padre1: 
    hijo1: "son1"
    hijo2: "son2"
```

por tanto rails simplemente se queda con el último. Además lo que haces en las siguientes líneas tampoco es parte de un archivo yaml válido:

```
padre2: "father2"
  hijo1: "son1"
```

padre2 no puede tener a la vez un valor ("father2") y hijo1 anidado, revisa las [especificaciones de YAML](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) para ver que estructuras son válidas y cuáles no.

Respecto a como ordenar tus traducciones, da lo mismo que tengan la misma jerarquía. Si el hijo1 tiene el mismo valor tanto en padre1 como padre2, simplemente podrías crear una jerarquía plana:

```
en: 
  padre1: "father1"
  padre2: "father2"
  hijo1: "son1"
  hijo2: "son2"
```

ahora, si son distintas, usa algún identificador donde venga la traducción:

```
en: 
  padre1: 
    valor: "father1"
    hijo1: "son1"
    hijo2: "son2"
  padre2:
    valor: "father2"
    hijo1: "son1"
    hijo2: "son2"
```

o para hacerlo mas estandarizado, que todos tengan el mismo atributo con el valor, aunque el yaml quede un poco más verboso:

```
en: 
  padre1: 
    valor: "father1"
    hijo1:
      valor: "son1"
    hijo2:
      valor: "son2"
  padre2:
    valor: "father2"
    hijo1:
      valor: "son1"
    hijo2:
      valor: "son2"
```

En realidad no hay una "forma" para hacerlo, simplemente tienes que adaptar el yaml a la naturaleza de tus datos.